# Render Route after asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm building my first React app. I'm trying to render some Routes from react-router-dom. 
From the main component I call to my api to get a json object, then I update the state. The problem is my child component doesn't re-render after I have set the new state so I don't have props in the child components. I have used some functions like forcerender and componentWillReceiveProps but still doesn't work

I'm sure it's not a big problem but I have been trying to fix this for a couple of hours and I haven't been able to make it work.

Here is my latest attempt:

```js
class DetectorEfficiencyCalculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
        detectors: []
    };
        axios.get(`/detectors`)
      .then(res => {
        const detectors = res.data;
        this.setState({ detectors });
           console.log('state updated')
      });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DetectorEfficiencyCalculator">
          <RoutesHandler detectors={this.state.detectors}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RoutesHandler extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state        = { detectors: props.detectors } ;
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({detectors:nextProps.detectors})
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
      render() {
      console.log('render')
    return (
      <div className="RoutesHandler">
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/frontend/Detectors' component={DetectorList} detectors={this.props.detectors}/>
              <Route  path='/frontend/Detectors/:number' component={DetectorDetail} detectors={this.props.detectors}/>
          </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }

}



class DetectorList extends Component {

  render () {
        console.log('renderList')
      if (!this.props.detectors) {
          return null;
      }
    return (
      <ul>
          {this.props.detectors.map(u => {
              return (
                  <Detector
                      id={u.id}
                      name={u.name}
                      single={u.single}
                      threshold={u.threshold}
                      angle={u.angle}
                  />
              );
          })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: put the `console.log('renderList', this.props.detectors)` in DetectorList component and check whether you are getting the updated value or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got into the solution: The route renders a function in which I render the component and load it with the props I need.

```js
        this.RenderDetectorDetail = (props) => {
            return (
                <DetectorDetail detectors={this.props.detectors}/>
            );
    };
    
     <Route  exact path='/frontend/Detectors' render={this.RenderDetectorList} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
class DetectorEfficiencyCalculator extends Component {
  state={detectors:[]}

  componentDidMount(){
    const self = this;
    axios.get(`/detectors`) //do it here...
      .then(res => {
        const detectors = res.data;
        self.setState({ detectors });
           console.log('state updated')
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DetectorEfficiencyCalculator">
          <RoutesHandler detectors={this.state.detectors}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RoutesHandler extends Component{       
   render() {
      console.log('render')
    return (
      <div className="RoutesHandler">
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/frontend/Detectors' component={DetectorList} detectors={this.props.detectors}/>
              <Route  path='/frontend/Detectors/:number' component={DetectorDetail} detectors={this.props.detectors}/>
          </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }

}



class DetectorList extends Component {

  render () {
        console.log('renderList')
      if (!this.props.detectors) {
          return null;
      }
    return (
      <ul>
          {this.props.detectors.map(u => {
              return (
                  <Detector
                      id={u.id}
                      name={u.name}
                      single={u.single}
                      threshold={u.threshold}
                      angle={u.angle}
                  />
              );
          })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, you dont want to do any ajax calls or db access in the constructor, this is not the right way to do it in React since the constructor can be called multiple times. Instead use the React component lifecycle method componentDidMount to initiate the api call. In addition I used a variable (self) to hold a reference to the component (this) so I can use it in the axios promise handler.

Comment: I tried this but still won't work. When I render the child component like <DetectorList detectors={this.state.detectors}/> it renders the propes correctly with the data from the api, but when I render it as           <Switch>
            <Route path='/frontend/Detectors' component={DetectorList} detectors={this.state.detectors}/>
          </Switch>  It will never update it's props. I think I'm not using properly the switch or Route components, Any Ideas why?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the Switch? 
I have done many complex React applications and have never used that component from ReactRouter, not saying you dont need it just trying to figure out the use case.

Comment: Im using switch because I copied it from a example. After some days trying to solve this I still don't have any clue how to solve it :(

Comment: I think I would forget about the switch if I were you. It seems like an unnecessary complication for this use case.